# How to get a google maps search to return results only from the currently visible region?

Tags: google-maps

Is there an easy way to use the google maps searchbar to only recieve results from the currently visible region, or a set of coordinates?

I've been googleing for a while and can't seem to find a simple solution for this which I guess should be used by many sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search in two ways 
1) In a bounding box 
2) In a circle of certain radius

I think it is possible as it says [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#Search)

Hope this helps
Myra